# Could you teach me how to connect cloud functions in GCP to cloud SQL?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, mysql-python

I saw the GCP quick start(https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-connect-functions) and tried to connect Google cloud functions to My SQL of cloud SQL. Actually the website is using   HTTP trigger, but I want to use **"Finalize/Create" action in GCS as a trigger** of the cloud functions. Therefore I used following python code and txt code.

【MAIN.PY】

```
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud import storage

# Set the following variables depending on your specific
# connection name and root password from the earlier steps:


def sql_select(data, context):
    connection_name = "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
    db_password = "DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD"
    db_name = "DATABASE_NAME"
    db_user = "root" 
    driver_name = 'mysql+pymysql'
    query_string = '"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)'
    print("I am here 1")

    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername=driver_name,
            username=db_user,
            password=db_password,
            database=db_name,
            query={query_string},
        ),
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800)
    

    # stmt = sqlalchemy.text('INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) values ("third guest", "Also this one");')
    # try:
    #     with db.connect() as conn:
    #         conn.execute(stmt)
    # except Exception as e:
    #     return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
    # return 'ok'
```

【REQUIREMENTS.TXT】

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18

    PyMySQL==0.9.3

Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
Pillow==5.4.1
qrcode==6.1
six==1.12.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
google-cloud-storage==1.23.0
```

And I tried to test the code by pushing "testing function" tab. But I have following error and couldn't connect cloud functions I made to cloud SQL(My SQL).

【The error message】

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I tried to change to latest version of sqlalchemy. But I couldn't solve the error.
And i have no idea to solve the problem.
Are there any solutions to connect cloud functions to cloud SQL?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The link you referenced **should** give you almost everything you need.

You should (!?) be able to trigger the function for the GCS bucket events but you'll need to ensure you deploy the function correctly:

See: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize

You'll need to `import sqlalchemy`. You've included the package in `requirements.txt` but missed the second step.

You'll need to update the values of `connection_name`, `db_password` etc. after having created the Cloud SQL instance, database etc.

I think your `query_string` statement is incorrect and would be better as:

```py
query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})
```

That's possibly the origination of the error.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your big help!

I changed the query_string = dict...    and some part. 

and the final code I use is bellow
`query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})`
Thank you